# react-native-calendar : selected ON/OFF when date is selected

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using [react-native-calendar](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars) for my project. I can `mark on` the calendar when I press on a date. But I want to `mark off` when marked date is pressed again.

This is my function code:

```
 onDayPress = (day) => {
        const _selectedDay = Moment(day.dateString).format(_format);
        this.setState(({pressedDate}) => ({
         pressedDate: {
          ...pressedDate,
          [_selectedDay] : {
          selected: true
          }
       },
       selectedDay:_selectedDay
     }))
     console.log(this.state.pressedDate, 'this.state.pressedDate')
    }
```

In my calendar

```
<Calendar
           style={styles.calendarBox}
           markedDates={this.state.pressedDate}
           onDayPress={this.onDayPress}
           markingType={'multi-dot'}
           monthFormat={'yyyy MMMM'}/>
```

Is there a way I can mark on and off dates? Also, I want only to mark up to three dates. Is this possible?

Also, when I `console.log('this.state.pressedDate')` I get undefined at first. When I click on it again then I get the value any idea why this is happening?.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can mark on and off dates?

As you can see in [`Calendar` implementation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/blob/e3201dff2bbb92a5fd03f1d16ca40c239ed92f29/src/calendar/index.js#L99-L106), it only updates when you pass difference `current` to this component. You can do this trick:

```
  _onDayPress = day => {
    const { dateString } = day;
    const { markedDates } = this.state;

    const isMarkedBefore = !!(
      markedDates[`${dateString}`] && 
      markedDates[`${dateString}`].selected
    );
    markedDates[`${dateString}`] = { selected: !isMarkedBefore };

    this.setState(
     { ...this.state, markedDates, current: null }, 
     () => {
       this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        current: dateString
       });
     });
  };


  ...
  <Calendar
       style={styles.calendarBox}
       current={this.state.current}
       markedDates={this.state.markedDates}
       onDayPress={this._onDayPress}
       markingType={'multi-dot'}
       monthFormat={'yyyy MMMM'}/>
```

> when I console.log('this.state.pressedDate') I get undefined at first. When I click on it again then I get the value any idea why this is happening?.

`setState` is asynchronous function so if you want to see what your state change after that you should log in second callback parameter like

```
   this.setState({...someState}, () => {
     console.log(this.state);
   })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems like your code looks right but for some reason, when I press on a certain day, it won't mark dates. Could you please check? thanks :)